# GetExternalFilesDir() is returning null

Tags: android, xamarin

I am facing problems with getting the path. i get the value fine in 4.4 and above but on 4.3 i get a null value

```
var path = AndroidDownloader.MainApplicationContext.GetExternalFilesDir (global::Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMovies);
```

Edit: I added 100Mb storage to sd card and it is working fine for both now, but how can i handle this if sd card is not present,
also shouldn't GetExternalFilesDir() give the path like this /storage/sdcard0/  why is it checking for sd card ??

Edit 2: if SD card is not specified in emulator the path from above code is null irrespective of android version, whats the workaround for this???
will this work normally in real devices?

Comment: Your edit makes it sound like you are using an emulator, which typically does not have external storage unless you attach an emulated sd card.  This is documented to return null if the external storage is unavailable - **in which case you cannot store things there**.

Comment: I do not know xamarin but find it strange that you look for DirectoryMovies in external files dir. Normally that resides in getExternalStorageDirectory(). Does xamarin have that too?

Comment: Expanding on @greenapps comment, the corresponding API for `getExternalStorageDirectory()` is `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory`.

Comment: @ChrisStratton so in emulator if i dont specify the sd card and just keep internal memory as say 500 mb still i cant get files there, also wont i face the same problem on devices with no sd cards

Comment: The situation with an emulator is like that of some of the oldest Android devices that relied on an sd card as their *only* implementation of External Storage, but quite different from the majority of modern ones which emulate their primary External Storage using the same blocks of flash available for internal storage.  That said, I do believe there are a handful of modern devices which still depend on a removable SD card as their only External Storage.

Comment: The only way you can handle the External Storage being unavailable is to either make that part of your app optional, defer those options unless/until it is available, or fallback to internal storage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton making optional is something that i cant do, i would go to internal storage but i dont think downloadmanager directly downloads to internal storage

Comment: In that case downloads won't work when there is no external storage anyway, so just concentrate on gracefully disabling that functionality (ie, without crashing) when that occurs.  Or else implement your own downloader service which can store elsewhere.